# What is application of gamma distribution on pure math or probability theory?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

What is application of gamma distribution on pure math or probability theory?

i saw it on several probability textbook as a definition, but it seems to me mathematician  couldn't derived it if it is coming from physics not mathematics...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that in Bayesian inference (a major tool of probabilistic robotics), the gamma distribution is the conjugate prior to many likelihood distributions: the Poisson, exponential, normal,etc. For more information, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Conjugate_prior).